# FilePath as a URL, Visual Basic Desktop App

Tags: vb.net, url, dataset, filepath

I am using the code below to bind data from a XML file in my PC. It works fine when using a local PC filePath, but when I change the location of the XML filePath to an URL which is listed [below](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=42FE4354E1EDA2AE&id=42FE4354E1EDA2AE!674). it simply doesn't work. I made this xml file public in my onedrive but still doen´t work. Do I need to download the file and then readXML?

Many Thanks,

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml

Public Class NasgoLive

Private Sub RefreshButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RefreshButton.Click, RefreshButton.Click

    MessageBox.Show("Done")

    Me.BackColor = Color.FloralWhite

    Dim filePath As String = "Complete path where you saved the XML"
    AuthorsDataSet.ReadXml("https://onedrive.live.com/?  cid=42FE4354E1EDA2AE&id=42FE4354E1EDA2AE%21674")

    alliancehorizonvalue.DataSource = AuthorsDataSet
    alliancehorizonvalue.DataMember = "alliancehorizon"
    arcticovalue.DataSource = AuthorsDataSet
    arcticovalue.DataMember = "arctico"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the file first. [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx) supports just a file name, not url.

<strike>You could download the file with a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20WebClient) (not tested):</strike>

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    data = client.DownloadData("https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=42FE4354E1EDA2AE&id=42FE4354E1EDA2AE!674");
}
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\myfile.xml", data);
```

**EDIT**:
For downloading you need to use [OneDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#downloading_files)

Comment: For downloading you need to use OneDrive API, edit my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks. But then how do i use the same file in DataSet.ReadXML?

Comment: First you download the file using OneDriveAPI. Then it exists on your local drive and you can use it as you did before. `AuthorsDataSet.ReadXml("c:\myfile.xml");`

Comment: it´s very diffficult to use onedrive/skydrive as a source. :s Thanks anyway

Comment: So ist this an answer to your question? - Then mark it. Thanks.